# Cannot find file <event2\event.h> after install libevent in my mac os

Tags: macos, libevent

my mac os is the latest version , i install libevent in the following steps:

```
cd directory
./configure && make
sudo make install
```

and install successfully.

but in my Xcode the  file not found, can someone help me?

Comment: do you really have a \ and not a / ?

try <event2/event.h> ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your project setting correctly (xcode is a pain in the butt). My "Header Search Paths" is set to $(SRCROOT)/../../../libevent (non-recursive). Seriously... this took almost an hour to configure properly. Much easier in Visual Studio which has navigation tools.